# Can't figure out how to style text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to style this text and for some reason, I can't figure out why my styling isn't working. I'm not new to html and css so I really don't know why nothing I try is working. It was working before I made a few changes to my css but now when I do add styling to it it's not working

[image]

here is my css:

```
.text-size{
    margin-top:20px; 
    font-size: 27px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
    font-weight: bold;

}

.row{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.mission{
    font-size: 20px;
}

.space{
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.btn{
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.btn-primary{
        color: #000 !important;
    background-color: #7ed321  !important;
    border-color: #7ed321  !important;
    font-family: Arial Rounded MT Bold;
    font-weight: bold !important;
 }

.line{
      overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.who-we-are{
    font-family: Roboto Condensed;
  font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
 }

.who-we-are:before, 
.who-we-are:after {
  background: #ddd;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
  width: 96%;
}

.who-we-are:before {
   right: 100%;
}

.who-we-are:after {
  left: 100%;
}

.our-work{
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.view-btn{
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.inner-caption{
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;  
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.carousel-caption{     
      right: 15% !important;
      left: 57% !important;
      top: 12% !important;
}

.btn-shadow{
  -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 3px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 6px 3px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 6px 3px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.carousel-head{
  font-family: Roboto Condensed;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.carousel-body{
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.part2{
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  // width:100%;
margin-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-top: 20px;

}

.resize-image{
   border: 3px solid #000;
    padding: 0 !important;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;

}

.program-item{
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }

  .col-xs-12{
    padding:0 !important;
  }



h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Roboto Condensed;
}

.program-text{
  font-family: Roboto Condensed;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

this is what I am trying to style:

```
h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Roboto Condensed;
}
```

here is my html:

```
<h3 class="zip-text text-center">We have partnered with Zip Zap Zop: Improv for Kids! Click <a href=" http://www.zipzapzopimprov.com/" target="_blank">here</a> to learn more</h3>
<a href=" http://www.zipzapzopimprov.com/" target="_blank"><img class="center-block" src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/zip.jpeg" alt="" /></a>
```

I also tried adding styling to the `.zip-text` class and still won't work

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your code seems to work fine to me http://jsbin.com/yipodutedo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: That is so strange. I have no idea why it isn't working for me.

Comment: Have you cleared the cache? try from different browser.

Comment: the only way it's working is if I add a style tag within the html which I am totally against but I can't see any other way

Comment: In the screenshot, I can see just the edge of an error in the console - might be worth investigating.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your markup pre/post this snippet of html is complete (no missing closing tags)? Although it looks correct from what I can see via the browser pic, some browsers may assume the correct markup.

Comment: Yeah. I mean, it was working before but now it just randomly stopped and I can't add any styling to it whatsoever